# Bad credentials though valid on a spring /authenticate token generator endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to build a route, processed in Spring, to generate a token if the user/password submited in the body are valid. Only in that scenario it responds with the token.

The problem is that I'm Posting the correct username and password, exactly as stored in DB but I keep getting a "bad credentials" error.
This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody JwtRequest authenticationRequest) throws Exception {
    try {
        LOGGER.info("Received a request to generate a token for user: "+authenticationRequest.getUsername()+"/"+authenticationRequest.getPassword());

        final UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authenticationRequest.getUsername());
        System.out.println(userDetails);
        // Logs: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@7ee29d27: Username: thisWasTheGoodUserName; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: Admin
        // And also logs the hibernate query:
        //    select
        //        employee0_.id as id1_0_,
        //        employee0_.employee_name as employee_name2_0_,
        //        employee0_.pwd as pwd3_0_,
        //        employee0_.user_name as user_nam4_0_ 
        //    from
        //        employees employee0_ 
        //    where
        //        employee0_.user_name=?

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, authenticationRequest.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities());
        // This step gets executed

        authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        // And the same query to the DB is logged, one that I can run on dbeaver manually and get results from:
        //    select
        //        employee0_.id as id1_0_,
        //        employee0_.employee_name as employee_name2_0_,
        //        employee0_.pwd as pwd3_0_,
        //        employee0_.user_name as user_nam4_0_ 
        //    from
        //        employees employee0_ 
        //    where
        //        employee0_.user_name=?
        // And throws exception in this authenticate
        
        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetails);

        TokenSucess tokenSuccessResponse = new TokenSucess(true, new JwtResponse(token));
        LOGGER.info("Obtained token with success ");
        return new ResponseEntity<TokenSucess>(tokenSuccessResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TokenError tokenErrorResp = new TokenError(false, "Error generating token.");
        LOGGER.error("Error generating a token. Details: "+ e);
        return new ResponseEntity<TokenError>(tokenErrorResp, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

This is the method I'm using in the service:

```
@Service
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Employee emp = employeeRepository.findByUserName(username);
        if (emp == null ) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Employee not found with username: " + username);
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("Admin"));

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(emp.getUserName(), emp.getPassword(), authorities);
    }
}
```

The security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        try {
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    // don't authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error handling http security configs. Details: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the curl example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:<port>/authenticate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "thisWasTheGoodUserName",
    "password": "123454321"
}'
```

Already tried with diferent scenarios in DB:

```
1. thisWasTheGoodUserName/123454321
2. thisWasTheGoodUserName/$2y$12$Mj0PRHipe14Wgm5c/GOuO.RyhjhuwRwoQYUnK8LcgsvHzQ4weYHGm (bcrypted 123454321)
```

Using several "step into" I found that the problem is happening in the following function - `/Users/<user>/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.0.3.RELEASE/spring-security-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.class`, even though the passwords are se same string:

```
protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
        this.logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
        throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
    } else {
        String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        // presentedPassword is exactly the same as the one in userDetails.getPassword() but the matcher returns False...

        if (!this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            this.logger.debug("Authentication failed: password does not match stored value");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong and causing the following Exception?

```
ERROR c.r.t.s.c.JwtAuthenticationController - Error generating a token. Details: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials
```

**Note**: found the problem causing all this: the stored password in the DB was encrypted using an online bcrypt generator... The value does not match the generated bcrypt encoded password even though they are the same string.

Comment: what your AuthenticationProvider? do you have it? AuthenticationManager use it to authenticate your post. if not, you should customize a AuthenticationProvider. And please provide your SecurityConfig here.

Comment: @jacky-neo added the security config and more details on the problem. I've been debuging further and also added more on the supposed problem location

Comment: Do you have define a PasswordEncoder？Is it BCryptPasswordEncoder? Why step into a DaoAuthenticationProvider without configure before？I am confused it. I suggest you define self AuthenticationProvider and walk around it. In your provider, you compare posted pwd and db's pwd.

Comment: @jacky-neo Added the full webSecurityConfig file if it helps. Didn't understand your comment on "Why step into a DaoAuthenticationProvider without configure before？I am confused it. I suggest you define self AuthenticationProvider and walk around it."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you can do a customized authenticate via AuthenticationProvider. You should comment configureGlobal(). The below is sample of WebSecurityConfig.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

   // @Autowired
   // private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);

    //@Autowired
    //public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    //    auth.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    //}

    //@Bean
    //public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    //    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    //}

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){


        return new AuthenticationProvider(){

            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {

            
                String username= request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");


                Employee user= employeeRepository.findByUserName(username);
                if (emp == null ) {
                  throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Employee not found with username: " 
                  + username);
                }

                // validate pwd by yourself. 
                // you should use same bcrypt generator to validate when saving pwd in DB
                if(!UserUtils.validatePassword(password, user.getPassword())){
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("wrong password!");
                }
                

                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("Admin"));               

                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,
                        null, authorities);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
                return true;
            }

        };
    }



    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        try {
            httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                    // don't authenticate this particular request
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().
                    // all other requests need to be authenticated
                            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
                            exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

            // Add a filter to validate the tokens with every request
            httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error handling http security configs. Details: "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```